# How to execute this query in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

Do you know how can i do this query in cakephp with the helper find?

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM brand 
        WHERE nom LIKE '$nom%'  AND 
              genre LIKE '$genre%' AND     
              mouvement LIKE '$mouvement%' AND 
              forme LIKE '$forme%' AND 
              prix >= '$mini' AND 
               prix <= '$maxi' 
         ORDER BY prix ASC";
```

I do something like this but it doesn't work

```
   $results=$this->Model->find('all',array('conditions'=>array
  ('AND'=>array('name   LIKE'=>$nom,'genre LIKE'=>$genre,
  'mouvement LIKE'=>$mouvement,.....))));
```

Thank you in advance for your reply ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$this->Brand->find('all',array
(
    'conditions' => array
    (
        'Brand.nom LIKE' => "{$nom}%",
        'Brand.genre LIKE' => "{$genre}%",
        'Brand.mouvement LIKE' => "{$mouvement}%",
        'Brand.forme LIKE' => "{$forme}%",
        'Brand.prix >=' => $mini,
        'Brand.prix <=' => $maxi
    ),
    'order' => array('Brand.prix' => 'ASC')
));
```